# Showing a sum of $\vert f(x+k)\vert $ belongs to $L^{\infty}$ if $f,f'\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

I am working on this

> Suppose that $f,f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\sum_{k= 0} ^{\infty}\vert f(x+k)\vert\in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}.$

Idea: Let $i$ be any integer. $\int_i ^{i+1}\vert \sum_k f(x+k) \vert dx=\sum_k \int _i ^{i+1}\vert f(x+k)\vert=\sum_k \int _{i+k} ^{i+1+k}\int \vert f(x) \vert \\\le \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}\vert f\vert <\infty$ since $f$ is in $L^1$.

How do I use the fact that $f'$ is integrable, and how can I show the series belongs to $L^{\infty}([a,b])$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to approximate $f(x)$ by integrals involving $f$ and $f'$. We actually have 
$$\left|f(x)-\int_x^{x+1}f(t)\mathrm dt \right|\leqslant \int_x^{x+1}\left| f'(t)\right| \mathrm dt.  $$
This follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. Indeed, 
$$\int_x^{x+1}f(t)\mathrm dt-f(x) =\int_0^1 (f(x+t)-f(x))\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\int_0^t f'(x+s)\mathrm ds\mathrm dt,$$
then switch the integrals.

As a consequence, for each $x\in\mathbf R$, 
$$|f(x)|\leqslant  \int_x^{x+1}\left| f(t)\right| \mathrm dt+\int_x^{x+1}\left| f'(t)\right| \mathrm dt,$$
hence 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|f(x+j)|\leqslant\int_{x}^{\infty} \left| f(t)\right| \mathrm dt+  \int_{x}^{\infty}\left| f'(t)\right| \mathrm dt .$$

Comment: When you say fundamental theorem of calculus, I assume you mean: If $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $[a,b]$ and $f'\in L^1([a,b]),$ then $f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^bf'$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{ $

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I follow but I don't see how it implies the series is in $L^1([a,b])$. Does the last inequality hold for $x$ in an interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: The series has to be in $\mathbb L^\infty[a,b]$ (it is also in $\mathbb L^1$ but it is not asked).